# Redirect to page with parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to have a page with a list of recordings accessed with `/recordings`. By clicking on any of the recordings I want to be redirected to that recording's page `/recording/:recordingId`.

I have the following routes, made using 'react-router':

```
                <Route path="recordings" component={RecordingList}/>
                    <Route path="recording/:recordingId" component={Recording}/>
                </Route>
```

In the `RecordingList` react component I have the following links for each recording:

```
  var recordingsHtml = new Array()
  recordings.forEach(function(value, i) {
      recordingsHtml.push(
        <li key={i} style={{clear: "both"}}>
          <Link to={"recording"} params={{recordingId: i}}>{value.title}</Link>
        </li>
      );
  });
```

So I would expect that when I click the first link I would be redirected to `recording/1`.

However, I am redirected to `/recording` so a URL without any id.
Also, I am getting this message:

```
Location "recording" did not match any routes
```

So how can I make the links work well?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version of react router you use, the solution may be diferent. [Url params](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#props-1) are currently given in an object passed to the props `to`. The object property `query` must be filled.